# Unexpected syntax error from MingW compiling a simple C program

Tags: c, mingw

Complete Novice alert :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{ puts("C Rocks!");
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled with MinGW, it shows two errors:

1. syntax error near unexpected token ( in the beginning
2. and int main ()

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: It does? I honestly don't see a problem with the code. add a space after the `#include` for the sake of readability and it's good to add a new line after the closing brace (some compilers emit a warning) but otherwise I see no issues here. Works fine [here](http://codepad.org/EKJNq85S) too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon. The layout of the code is a little skew-whiff, but nothing that the compiler should be complaining about as a syntax error.  Ideally, you should copy and paste the error messages exactly, file name, line numbers and all.  What was the command line you used to compile this?

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue. Check for illegal characters in the path name such as spaces or brackets. Your code looks correct so the issue isn't there. If all else fails, go back to the basics. Make sure you're actually using "gcc file.c -o file.exe" to output the correct file. For some reason, i completely forgot to use 'gcc', even though I had been using MinGW for over  month.

Answer (score 0):

Install mingw in a path without spaces.MinGW will experience problems with such paths. Thus, i strongly recommend that you do not install MinGW in any location with spaces in the path name reference; i.e. you should avoid installing into any subdirectory
of "Program Files" or "My Documents", or the like.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code. Is the first time you compile something? It seems to be a problem with the MingW. It can be spaces in the path, for example.

To avoid some beginner problems, you can use an IDE, like Dev-C++(http://www.bloodshed.net/devcpp.html), as it can compile C and C++ code.